# feature extraction using ASM(Active shape model)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, training-data

Suppose we made an ASM shape extraction. 
In that case, which parameter would be used for the training, x or b? 
x = x.mean + P.b

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit weird, in that the parameter is the *result* of training, not "used" for it.

One wishes to generate a model `X = X_bar + P*b`. Then the training set of images (say, `T_s = {X_i}`) is used to generate both the parameters `X_bar` and `P`.